# How to fill NaN values by imputation, in the Titanic Age column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, imputation

I am doing the Titanic kaggle competition and I am currently trying to impute missing `Age` values.

The idea is to compute the mean `Age` per `[Pclass, Sex]` group on the training set and then use this information to replace `NaN` on the train and test set.

This is what I have so far:

```
meanAgeTrain = train.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'])['Age'].transform('mean')
    
for df in [train, test]:
    df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(meanAgeTrain)
```

The problem is that this still leaves some NaN values in the test set while eliminating all Nans in the training set. I assume this has something to do with indices.

What I would need is that:

1. Compute mean of each Pclass/Sex group in the training set
2. Map all NaN values in the training set to the right mean
3. Map all NaN values in the test set to the right mean (lookup by Pclass/Sex and not based on indices)

How can this be done correctly using Pandas?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the suggestions. The one by @Reza works, but I don't 100% understand it. So I am trying to come up with my own solution.

This works, but I am new to Pandas and would like to know if there is an easier way to achieve it.

```
trainMeans = self.train.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'])['Age'].mean().reset_index()

def f(x):
    if x["Age"] == x["Age"]:  # not NaN
        return x["Age"]
    return trainMeans.loc[(trainMeans["Pclass"] == x["Pclass"]) & (trainMeans["Sex"] == x["Sex"])]["Age"].values[0]

 self.train['Age'] = self.train.apply(f, axis=1)
 self.test['Age'] = self.test.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Especially the if in the function looks not like a best practice to me. I would need a way to apply the function only to NaN ages.

**EDIT 2**:

Turns out that resetting the index is making things more complicated and slow because after grouping the index is already exactly what I want to use as the mapping key. This is faster and easier:

```
trainMeans = self.train.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex'])['Age'].mean()

def f(x):
    if not np.isnan(x["Age"]):  # not NaN
        return x["Age"]
    return trainMeans[x["Pclass"], x["Sex"]]

self.train['Age'] = self.train.apply(f, axis=1)
self.test['Age'] = self.test.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Can this be further simplified?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220685/discussion-on-question-by-simon-h-pandas-how-to-impute-test-set-based-on-group).

Answer (score 5):

- You will see that the two fill methods, **groupby fillna with mean** and **random forest regressor**, are within a couple of 1/100's of a year of each other

  - See the bottom of the answer for the statistical comparison.

### Fill nan values with the mean

- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with [`.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).
- The following code fills `nans` with the mean for each group, for the entire dataset.
- [Titanic Age Analysis](https://trenton3983.github.io/files/titanic.html#Age)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# map sex to a numeric type
df.sex = df.sex.map({'male': 1, 'female': 0})

# Populate Age_Fill
df['Age_Fill'] = df['age'].groupby([df['pclass'], df['sex']]).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

# series with filled ages
groupby_result = df.Age_Fill[df.age.isnull()]

# display(df[df.age.isnull()].head())
 survived  pclass     sex  age  sibsp  parch     fare embarked   class    who  adult_male deck  embark_town alive  alone  Age_Fill
        0       3    male  NaN      0      0   8.4583        Q   Third    man        True  NaN   Queenstown    no   True  26.50759
        1       2    male  NaN      0      0  13.0000        S  Second    man        True  NaN  Southampton   yes   True  30.74071
        1       3  female  NaN      0      0   7.2250        C   Third  woman       False  NaN    Cherbourg   yes   True  21.75000
        0       3    male  NaN      0      0   7.2250        C   Third    man        True  NaN    Cherbourg    no   True  26.50759
        1       3  female  NaN      0      0   7.8792        Q   Third  woman       False  NaN   Queenstown   yes   True  21.75000
```

### Fill nan values from RandomForestRegressor

- [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)
- [Kaggle: Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/saisivasriram/titanic-feature-understanding-from-plots)

  - *Age seems to be promising feature. So it doesn't make sense to simply fill null values out with median/mean/mode.*
  - Based on the results here, I don't think it makes much difference

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# load dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# map sex to a numeric type
df.sex = df.sex.map({'male': 1, 'female': 0})

# split data
train = df.loc[(df.age.notnull())]  # known age values
test = df.loc[(df.age.isnull())]  # all nan age values

# select age column
y = train.values[:, 3]

# select pclass and sex
X = train.values[:, [1, 2]]

# create RandomForestRegressor model
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=2000, n_jobs=-1)

# Fit a model
rfr.fit(X, y)

# Use the fitted model to predict the missing values
predictedAges = rfr.predict(test.values[:, [1, 2]])

# create predicted age column
df['pred_age'] = df.age

# fill column
df.loc[(df.pred_age.isnull()), 'pred_age'] = predictedAges 

# display(df[df.age.isnull()].head())
 survived  pclass  sex  age  sibsp  parch     fare embarked   class    who  adult_male deck  embark_town alive  alone  pred_age
        0       3    1  NaN      0      0   8.4583        Q   Third    man        True  NaN   Queenstown    no   True  26.49935
        1       2    1  NaN      0      0  13.0000        S  Second    man        True  NaN  Southampton   yes   True  30.73126
        1       3    0  NaN      0      0   7.2250        C   Third  woman       False  NaN    Cherbourg   yes   True  21.76513
        0       3    1  NaN      0      0   7.2250        C   Third    man        True  NaN    Cherbourg    no   True  26.49935
        1       3    0  NaN      0      0   7.8792        Q   Third  woman       False  NaN   Queenstown   yes   True  21.76513
```

### comparison of groupby an rfr

```py
print(predictedAges - groupby_result).describe())

count    177.00000
mean       0.00362
std        0.01877
min       -0.04167
25%        0.01121
50%        0.01121
75%        0.01131
max        0.02969
Name: Age_Fill, dtype: float64

# comparison dataframe
comp = pd.DataFrame({'rfr': predictedAges.tolist(), 'gb': groupby_result.tolist()})
comp['diff'] = comp.rfr - comp.gb

# display(comp)
      rfr        gb     diff
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 28.75266  28.72297  0.02969
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 28.75266  28.72297  0.02969
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 30.69903  30.74071 -0.04167
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 41.24592  41.28139 -0.03547
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 34.63090  34.61176  0.01913
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 26.51880  26.50759  0.01121
 21.76131  21.75000  0.01131
```

### Calculate means on a random training set

- This example calculates the mean of a random training set, an then fills the `nan` values in the training set and the test set
- Using [`pandas.DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), which will fill missing values in a dataframe column, from another dataframe, when both dataframes have a matching index, and the fill column is same.

  - *Pclass/Sex and not based on indices*, `pclass` and `sex` are set as the indices, which is how `.fillna` works.
- In this example, `train` is 67% of the data, and `test` is 33% of the data.

  - `test_size` and `train_size` can be set as needed, as per [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# load dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# map sex to a numeric type
df.sex = df.sex.map({'male': 1, 'female': 0})

# randomly split the dataframe into a train and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# select columns for X and y
X = df[['pclass', 'sex']]
y = df['age']

# create a dataframe of train (X, y) and test (X, y)
train = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
test = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# calculate means for train
train_means = train.groupby(['pclass', 'sex']).agg({'age': 'mean'})

# display train_means, a multi-index dataframe
                 age
pclass sex          
1      0    34.66667
       1    41.38710
2      0    27.90217
       1    30.50000
3      0    21.56338
       1    26.87163

# fill nan values in train
train = train.set_index(['pclass', 'sex']).age.fillna(train_means.age).reset_index()

# fill nan values in test
test = test.set_index(['pclass', 'sex']).age.fillna(train_means.age).reset_index()
```

Comment: great work adding the knn imputation to the model pipeline!

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a map for `Age`:

```
cols = ['Pclass', 'Sex']
age_class_sex = train.groupby(cols)['Age'].mean().reset_index()
```

Then merge it with test and train separately so the index is resolved

```
train['Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(train[cols].reset_index().merge(age_class_sex, how='left', on=cols).set_index('index')['Age'])
test['Age'] = test['Age'].fillna(test[cols].reset_index().merge(age_class_sex, how='left', on=cols).set_index('index')['Age'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives me NaN in both train and test set. I don't know how to debug this properly. What I can do is write a manual loop and look the value for each row up manually

Comment: sorry, it is because I don't have the dataset to check it, let me fix it

Comment: the code is fine, I guess it is because you might have 'nan' in Pclass and Sex in test or train. Have you removed Nan is Pclass and Sex already?

Comment: I double-checked and there are no Nans left in test or train

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: Is this the "Pandas way" to do it or is there an easier solution?

Comment: I edited the question and added a new possible solution. Would be great to hear your opinion and possible improvements!