# How can I transform a 2d array to a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I'm doing the titanic dataset on **kaggle**. The `Age` column has some missing values, and I tried to impute them using `sklearn.impute` `SimpleImputer`.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

titanic_data = pd.read_csv("../input/titanic/train.csv")

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan)


features = ['Age', 'Pclass']

X = titanic_data[features]
y = titanic_data.Survived

age_arr = X.Age.values.reshape(1, -1)

imputed_age = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(age_arr))

X.Age = imputed_age

print(imputed_age)
```

As shown above, I have some trouble arranging and converting those arrays and data columns. I need a proper way to make those a single column in the age column. When I print `imputed_age`, it gives me a dataframe where each age is a column. I want to make all of these in the same column, and how could I easily do the imputing and successfully put the imputed values into the dataframe again?

How could I put those imputed values into the dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: How to impute test set based on group aggregation computed on training set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650987/pandas-how-to-impute-test-set-based-on-group-aggregation-computed-on-training-s)

Comment: You used `reshape` to make the data 1 row with n columns, you can `reshape` it again to make it 1 column with n rows

Comment: Regardless of the issue in the question, adding imputed_age to the dataframe, this implementation does not fill the missing ages. Note, there are 891 values in the dataframe, but imputed_age has only 714 values, which is just the number of non-null values. See the duplicate for an appropriate solution for filling the NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on a forum elsewhere and someone gave me a solution. I'll put it here, and I've modified it a bit.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

features = ["pclass","age"]

X = df.loc[:,features]
y = df.survived

imputer = SimpleImputer()

age_transform = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(pd.DataFrame(X.age)),columns=["Age"])
```

I check your code and I found that if we input dataframe in imputer.fit_transform, we don't need to reshape to (1,-1).
So I just make age columns as dataframe and input it in imputer and fit_transform. And I think it works well.