# Machine learning Classification: Appending/ Attaching Prediction Column to original sataset with matching Index number

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I am building a machine learning binary classification model, I want to attach my `prediction column` to the original dataset `df`  so as to be able to compare raw prediction with ground truth `target column` with matching `index`. My dilemma is this-  in ML, the dataset is usually shuffled/randomized before splitting into `Train`, `Validation` and `Test` sets. See below:

Original dataset `df`

```
df

applicant_id, income, age, level_of_education, home_owner, gender, target
1001, 32400, 21, 0, 0, M, 0
1024, 76221, 46, 1, 1, F, 1
1706, 231000, 56, 3, 1, M, 1
1008, 38115, 48, 0, 1, M, 1 
.
.
.
.
9999, 47820, 37, 2, 0, F, 0
```

After partitioning `train_test_split` or `createDataPartition`  the sequence of the data is shuffled and randomized to prevent overfitting. So it looks like this (take note of the sequence of the  `applicant_id` column)

```
Train_df(Combined: X_train, y_train)

applicant_id, income, age, level_of_education, home_owner, gender, target
1001, 32400, 21, 0, 0, M, 0
9999, 47820, 37, 2, 0, F, 0
.
.
.
.
1008, 38115, 48, 0, 1, M, 1 

test_df (Combined: X_test, y_test)

applicant_id, income, age, level_of_education, home_owner, gender, target
1024, 76221, 46, 1, 1, F, 1
1706, 231000, 56, 3, 1, M, 1
```

My desired output :

```
#Key thing: I want to be able to track/trace and compare the the `target_label` with the `pred_label` in 
#the dataframe while maintain the `original sequence\index of the applicant_id`. 

#Lastly, I will like to know what row/record went to `train`, `val` and `test`  as seen in `final_df`

Final_df

applicant_id, income, age, level_of_education, home_owner, gender, target, pred_label, split_class
1001, 32400, 21, 0, 0, M, 0, 0, Train
1024, 76221, 46, 1, 1, F, 1, 1, Test
1706, 231000, 56, 3, 1, M, 1, 0, Test
1008, 38115, 48, 0, 1, M, 1, 1, Val
.
.
.
9999, 47820, 37, 2, 0, F, 0, 0, Train
```

Here is my code

```
# libraries

import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = df[:,0:7]
y = df[:,7]

# Data partition/Split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
history =model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# make class predictions with the model
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions= (y_pred > 0.5)


df['pred_label'] = predictions # this returns only for `test_set`, I want for ` train_set` and     `val_set` as well so I can combine in the `original_df`
```

Comment: If you predict on train data which is consumed by the same model for training, isn't it biased. Those prediction will anyways of no use just incase you want that do predict on X_train as well by simple model.predict

Comment: @UjjwalAgrawal I am predicting on test  hence `y_pred =  model.predict(X_test)`. Actually I am more interested in tracking the` index` for `applicant_id` in the `test` set

Comment: Maybe [How to fill NaN values by imputation, in the Titanic Age column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63651173) will help you.

Comment: Why not saving the applicant Id after test train split will not work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an 'index' column before train/test split. After split, you have train/test sets with index column. Do not use index column with training and testing. The order of the output will be same with input, then you can set the output to the dataframe with index column, so you are not lost. Below, I tried to explain the logic. Depending on your k-fold, I don't know how you are planning to combine the results. If you train your model once than giving your whole dataset to `predict` will be sufficient.

```
X['index_df'] = X.index
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X[['chosen_features_without_index']], y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
history =model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```